# ...calculate an eigenvector basis and its diagonal shape.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

In each of the cases below, decide whether the linear operator $T : \mathbb K^n \to \mathbb K^n$ given by its matrix $[T]_B$ is diagonalizable. If so, calculate an eigenvector basis and its diagonal shape.

a)$\begin{pmatrix} 6 & -3 & -2 \\ 4 & -1 & -2 \\ 10 & -5 & -3 \end{pmatrix}$ ; and $\mathbb K = \mathbb R, \mathbb C$

b)$\begin{pmatrix} -4 & -1 \\ 4 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ ; and $\mathbb K = \mathbb R$

---

My attempt

a)$det \alpha = det \begin{pmatrix} 6 - \lambda & -3 & -2 \\ 4 & -1 -\lambda & -2 \\ 10 & -5 & -3 -\lambda\end{pmatrix} = 0 \to -\lambda^3 + 2 \lambda^2 - \lambda + 2$,

so

$\lambda_1 = 2, \lambda_2 = i , \lambda_3 =-i $

$\lambda_1 = 2$

$\begin{pmatrix} 6 & -3 & -2 \\ 4 & -1 & -2 \\ 10 & -5 & -3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ c  \end{pmatrix} = 2 \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ c  \end{pmatrix} \to \begin{pmatrix} 6a -3b -2c \\ 4a -b -2c \\10a -5b - 3c  \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2a \\ 2b \\ 2c  \end{pmatrix} $

$6a -3b -2c = 2a;4a -b -2c = 2b; 10a -5b - 3c = 2c \to c = 2a, b = 0$

so

$v_1 = (1,0,2)$

$\lambda_2 = i$

$\begin{pmatrix} 6 & -3 & -2 \\ 4 & -1 & -2 \\ 10 & -5 & -3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} d \\ e \\ f  \end{pmatrix} = i \begin{pmatrix} d \\ e \\ f  \end{pmatrix} \to \begin{pmatrix} 6d -3e -2f \\ 4d -e -2f \\10d -5e - 3f  \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} d i \\ e i \\ f i  \end{pmatrix} \to d = e, f = \frac{3}{2}-\frac{i}{2}d$

$v_2 = (1,1,\frac{3}{2}-\frac{i}{2})$

$\lambda_3 = -i$

$\begin{pmatrix} 6 & -3 & -2 \\ 4 & -1 & -2 \\ 10 & -5 & -3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} w \\ y \\ z  \end{pmatrix} = -i \begin{pmatrix} w \\ y \\ z   \end{pmatrix} \to \begin{pmatrix} 6w -3y -2z \\ 4w -y -2z \\10w -5y - 3z  \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} w i \\ y i \\ z i  \end{pmatrix} \to w = y, z = \frac{3}{2}+\frac{i}{2}w$

$v_3 = (1,1,\frac{3}{2}-\frac{i}{2})$

Now we have

$\beta = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 2 & \frac{3}{2}-\frac{i}{2} & \frac{3}{2}+\frac{i}{2} \end{pmatrix}$

now, getting $\beta^{-1}$ and doing $\beta^{-1} \alpha \beta$ we get the diagonalization right?

b)$det \begin{pmatrix} -4 -\lambda & -1 \\ 4 & 0 -\lambda \end{pmatrix} = 0 \to \lambda^2 + 4\lambda + 4 = (x+2)^2 \to \lambda = -2$

$\begin{pmatrix} -4 & -1 \\ 4 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b  \end{pmatrix} = -2 \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b  \end{pmatrix} \to \begin{pmatrix} -4a - b \\ 4a  \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} -2a \\ -2b  \end{pmatrix} \to b = -2a \to v=(1,-2)$ is not diagonalizable ?

Not sure if b) is right? a) is not right, but is the procedure correct?

Thanks.

Comment: you are not solving the right equations for the eigenvectors. For a given value $\lambda,$ you are supposed to solve for $(A-\lambda I)v = 0.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a)$v_3 \text{ should be } (1,1,3/2+i/2) $, which is the conjugate vector of the one found for $i.$ You don't have to calculate the diagonal form. The theorem guarantees it will be$$ \text{diag}(2,i,-i)$$(b) Yes, the multiplicity of the eigenvalue is 2 and the dimension of the eigenspace is 1 so the matrix is not diagonalizable.